# От чего надо надо наследоваться, чтобы создать кастомизированный LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

От чего надо надо наследоваться, чтобы создать кастомизированный LinearLayout??
И можно ли создать кастомизированные уведомления (notifications)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> От чего надо надо наследоваться, чтобы создать кастомизированный LinearLayout?

От `LinearLayout` :)

Вот, просто для примера `LinearLayout` по умолчанию с вертикальной ориентацией

```
public class VerticalLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public VerticalLinearLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public VerticalLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public VerticalLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setOrientation(VERTICAL);
    }
}
```

**UPD**

Использовать можно так:

В XML

```
<package.VerticalLinearLayout
    android:id="linearID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button... />
    <!-- и т.д -->

</package.VerticalLinearLayout>
```

В Java

```
VerticalLinearLayout vll = (VerticalLinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearID);
```

Comment: Блиин(( Просто когда попробовал вписать LinearLayout, то не нашел данного файла( А как ещё сделать ссылку на определенный LinearLayout?? (по R.layout.LinearID)

Comment: То setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); не получается

Comment: СПАсибо, большое